# Vuforia Android VideoPlayback

Tags: java, android, видео, vuforia

Здравствуйте! В данным момент работаю с [Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com), примером [VideoPlayback](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps/video-playback-sample-app), дело в том, что пример я разобрал, работает как надо (заменил видео, вставил свои targets). Теперь нужно прикрутить все это в другое приложение, и никак не получается разбить этот пример. Нужных простеньких примеров в интернете не нашел, так что пишу сюда. Кто сталкивался с готовыми примерами или знает как прикрутить этот пример в свое приложение, пожалуйста, напишите.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: как помнится, есть ресурсы в папках `assets` и в `libs` которые переносятся. ну и реализация `QCARPlayerActivity`.

Comment: про ресурсы все понятно, а QCARPlayerActivity вообще не используется в примерах VideoPlayback ;(

Comment: где на сайте скачать ресурсы данного приложения?

Comment: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps

Download All Samples
Android (85.17 MB)